# C++ Arrays and Reading from file

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm creating an address book program that allow user to search by first name, last name,phone number and address. The user is prompted to enter a file name and the file is read into  an array. I'm having trouble modifying by existing SearchFirstName function to loop through array. I have read over this topic multiple times I'm just not understanding it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

File

```
Susan, Smith, 123 456 789 
101 Main Street
Bob, Smith, 567 345 9076 
456 Market Street
```

Header File

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;

enum Title {Mr, Mrs, Ms, Dr, NA};

struct NameType {
Title title;
string firstName;
string lastName;
};

struct AddressType {
  string street;
  string city;
  string state;
  string zip;
};

struct PhoneType {
  int areaCode;
  int prefix;
  int number;
};

  struct entryType {
  NameType name;
  AddressType address;
  PhoneType phone;
};

const int MAX_RECORDS = 50;

 struct addressBookType {
   entryType record[MAX_RECORDS];
   int numEntries;
};
```

Code

```
string bookArray[MAX_RECORDS];

int main()
{
   entryType userRecord;
   string filename;
   ifstream inData;
   char searchOption;

   OpenFile(filename, inData);

   MainMenu(inData, filename);

   return 0;
}

void OpenFile(string& filename, ifstream& inData)
{
    do {
       cout << "Enter file name to open: ";
       cin >> filename;

      inData.open(filename.c_str());

    if (!inData)
        cout << "File not found!" << endl;

} while (!inData);


  if(inData.is_open())
  {

       for(int i=0; i<MAX_RECORDS;i++)
       {
         inData>> bookArray[i];
       }
   }
}

// Searches passed file stream for a first name read from the user

 void SearchFirstName(ifstream& inData)
{
  string searchName;
  entryType userRecord;
  string normalSearchName, normalFirstName;
  char choice;
  bool found = false;

  cout << "Enter first name to search for: ";
  cin >> searchName;

  normalSearchName = NormalizeString(searchName);     // Convert name to all uppercase

  // Loop through all records in the file
  while (GetRecord(inData, userRecord)){

    normalFirstName = NormalizeString(userRecord.name.firstName);   // Convert retrieved string to all uppercase

    if (normalFirstName == normalSearchName) { // Requested name matches
        PrintRecord(userRecord);
        cout << "Is this the correct entry? (Y/N)";
        cin >> choice;
        choice = toupper(choice);
        cout << endl;

        if (choice == 'Y') {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Matching name was found before the end of the file
if (inData && !found){
    cout << "Record found: " << endl;
    PrintRecord(userRecord);
    cout << endl;
}
else if (!found)   // End of file. Name not found.
{
    cout << searchName << " not found!" << endl << endl;
}

// Clear file fail state and return to beginning
inData.clear();
inData.seekg(0);
}
```

My attempt

```
void SearchFirstName(ifstream& inData)
{
   string searchName;
   entryType userRecord;


cout << "Enter first name to search for: ";
cin >> searchName;

string newSearchName = NormalizeString(searchName);
string upFirst = NormalizeString(userRecord.name.firstName);

for (int i=0;i<MAX_RECORDS;i++)
{
    while(newSearchName == upFirst)
    {
        if (bookArray[i]== upFirst)
        {
            cout<<"Name Found";
            cout <<bookArray[i]; //test case
        }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Where are you having problems exactly?

Comment: @chbchb55 I edited my question to show what I tried. My code doesn't properly loop through the array in the SearchFirstName function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create your array, in this case it'll be an `std::vector` because that is more simple to use, by running your `GetRecord` function inside of a while loop and appending the result to the vector w/`vector_variable_name.push_back(NormalizeString(value_returned_from_GetRecord));`. The `NormalizeString` part is so you don't have to call it billions of times later.
2. Pass in your array like so `void SearchFirstName(std::vector<entryType> *in_data_arr>)`
3. Change your `while` loop to a `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < in_data_arr.size(); i++) {`
4. Inside the loop change `normalSearchName = NormalizeString(searchName);` to `normalSearchName = in_data_arr[i].name.firstName;`

And from there it should generally be identical.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using vectors

Comment: Yes, you've got two options: dynamically allocated array of strings using GetRecord (you'll have to reallocate it a couple of times), or just store it all in one string and then find out how many records there are and then create an array based on its size and manually load the whole thing in a for loop

Comment: I'd recommend using a vector, it only takes one and if you really need an array it's very simple to make an array out of a vector!